# Calculate the heat energy absorbed by an object without knowing its specific heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation

Say we know the mass of the object, the surface area, the temperature change, the time taken for the temperature to change and that all heat exchange happened through radiation

Can the stefan boltzman law or another formula be used to calculate the energy in joules absorbed by the object if we know the other parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The given information is insufficient to find the amount of energy absorbed.  In principle, you could figure it out if you knew either (*a*) how much energy is in the radiation and what fraction of it was absorbed by the body, or (*b*) the rate at which the body's temperature changes in response to a given transfer of heat (i.e., the specific heat.)

If there's no way of finding the specific heat, you would need to know the absorptivity of the body and the temperature of the incident radiation (assuming that it's well-approximated by a blackbody.)  You would also need to assume that the radiation is hitting all sides of the object evenly and not just from one side (say.)

Comment: Say we knew the absorptivity of the body and that the radiation was incident on the body evenly along with mass, surface area, temperature change, time to raise temperature, color temperature of the radiation would it be possible to get an approximate on the energy absorbed?

Comment: @DonaldBlake The entire radiative transfer depends on details of the emissivity/absorptivity of ALL the objects involved, and the entirety of the surroundings.   Such details as multiple reflections of radiant energy are usually not easy to model.